# Descargar, Subir y Mover archivos FTP PowerShell

Tags: linux, ftp, powershell, script

soy nuevo con PowerShell y estoy trabajando en un Script que tiene que descargar unos ficheros de diferentes rutas en una máquina Linux por FTP en otras rutas de una máquina Windows y además moverlos a otro destino dentro del Linux, básicamente así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento por lo que llevo investigado tengo que realizar la conexión por "webclient" y el código que llevo es el siguiente:

```
#Linux source folders 
$source1="/source1/"
$source2="/source2/" 
$source3="/source3/"     

#ftp server 
$ftp = "ftp://192.168.0.2/../../" 
$user = "usu1" 
$pass = "usu1"  

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  

#Download from source1 folder 
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem $source1 "*")){ 
    "Uploading $item..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
 }

#Download from source2 folder 
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem $source2 "*")){  
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
 }

#Download from source3 folder 
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem $source3 "*")){ 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
 }
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

```
Get-ChildItem : No se encuentra la ruta de acceso 'C:\source1\' porque no existe.
En línea: 16 Carácter: 23
```

Por lo que veo trata de buscar en el proio Windows.

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que podáis darme.

Saludos.